# Migrate Magento 1.9.1 to Magento 2.1

Tags: php, magento, ssh, magento-1.9, magento2

I want to migrate my Magento site from magneto 1.9.1 to Magento 2.1 using FTP and SSH.
For this I have referred below,
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/migration/bk-migration-guide.html
By referring the document I have made changes accordingly to the XML files but I am stuck at the 'Run the Data Migration Tool' step.

Can anyone help me how to run this tool. ?
I have run below commands in my SSH like,

```
su <Magento file system owner> -s /bin/bash -c <command> If the Magento file system owner does not allow logins you can do the following

sudo -u <Magento file system owner>  <command>
```

But it gave me error.
Can anyone one help me in solving this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid migration from Magento1 to Magento2 (whatever versions) is a much more complicated task: in fact, despite the migration tools and scripts shared by Magento and third-parties, this is very much more of a re-platforming task, rather than a migration.

You will have to rework every piece of customisation applied to your Magento1, in a Magento2-friendly way, reinstall all of the extensions and redo the theme, especially if you wish to migrate to the latest Magento 2.3.

Answer (score 0):

Install Fresh Magento2 anf follow below step run command

**01.** php -dmemory_limit=6G bin/magento module:disable Magento_Elasticsearch Magento_Elasticsearch6 Magento_Elasticsearch7

**02.** php -dmemory_limit=6G bin/magento setup:install --base-url=http://example.local/ --db-host=127.0.0.1 --db-name=magento2 --db-user=root --db-password= --admin-firstname=Magento --admin-lastname=User --admin-email=youremail.com --admin-user=admin --admin-password=Admin@123 --language=en_US --currency=GBP --timezone=Europe/London --use-rewrites=1 --backend-frontname=admin

**03.** Download Data migration tool from https://github.com/ubertheme/module-ubdatamigration

**04.** Perform Migration Step Given in readme of above link

----After Migration Completed

**05.** download Backup of `inventory_source_item` [Important for restoration]

**06.** TRUNCATE `inventory_source_item`;

**07.** INSERT IGNORE INTO `inventory_source_item` (source_code, sku, quantity, status)
select 'default', sku, qty, stock_status from (`cataloginventory_stock_status` as `lg` join `catalog_product_entity` as `prd` on((`lg`.`product_id` = `prd`.`entity_id`)));

**08.** php -dmemory_limit=6G bin/magento module:enable Magento_Elasticsearch Magento_Elasticsearch6 Magento_Elasticsearch7

**09.** php bin/magento config:set web/unsecure/base_url http://example.local/

**10.** php bin/magento config:set web/secure/base_url https://example.local/

**11.** php bin/magento config:set web/secure/use_in_adminhtml 1

**12.** php -dmemory_limit=5G bin/magento setup:upgrade

**13.** php -dmemory_limit=5G bin/magento setup:di:compile

**14.** php -dmemory_limit=5G bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f en_US

**15.** php -dmemory_limit=5G bin/magento indexer:reindex

**16.** php -dmemory_limit=5G bin/magento cache:flush

**17.** php -dmemory_limit=5G bin/magento cache:clean

**18.** php -dmemory_limit=5G bin/magento config:set web/secure/use_in_adminhtml 1

**You have all Done. Enjoy :)**